How do I seal under a radiator cover in a semi nice way?
I’m in a rental and for reasons unclear to me they glued the radiator covers in place. So I’m left with these huge gaps and no way to be able to seal the holes around the pipes to stop bugs and mice from coming in.
I could duct tape it and call it a day. But is there some more elegant material that I could use? I don’t own tools to say cut plywood and attach it. Also this is a rental so it needs to go when I leave. 

The only hole in your pic is in what must be assumed is the cover for the radiator. The radiator itself is in the home, so it is unclear how mice and bugs come in from outside. Perhaps a pic of the pipes and any opening around those would help.  However if the pipes are unseen and under the cover, it is confusing on why the seal must be "Semi nice".  Just fill them with plumbers putty or something similar.

This building has a roach issue. The pipes of the radiators as you know have usually big gaps around. If I could move the cover I’d seal around the pipes. But I can’t move the cover so I can’t reach the pipes unfortunately. So I want to seal the radiator cover itself. I wish I could seal the pipes.

You rent. If the building has a roach issue, contact the landlord or management company.  If others in the building have the same issue, organize them. There is strength in numbers.   I do not know the particulars of your radiator.

Yes - that is all being done. in the meanwhile I just discovered there is a wood grain like tape that I will order and use. I will keep you posted on how it looks!

I suspect you'll find that if you block one hole, they'll just find another.

Oh for sure. I have been sealing the whole baseboard perimeter for the past week. The pipes in the bathroom and etc.
I’ll never be able to seal 100% but if I get close to 99% it will still help.
